# How to hide a password on a form in VBA using MS Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, password-encryption

I have constructed a database using MS Access 2007. When opening the database, a form automatically pops up and covers the entire screen for the user to enter data. However, if the admin wishes to change anything in the tables, queries or forms behind this form, they would hit the **admin** button on the form which prompts them to enter a password. If the password is correct, the form will close and they're free to make any necessary adjustments. If the password is incorrect, the form will not close and their only option is to close the application altogether. The VBA code I have works, however how can I encrypt the text the user is typing? Here is the VBA Code

```
    Private Sub cmdAdmin_Click()
    Dim password As String

    password = InputBox("Please enter the password")

    If password = "passw0rd4" Then

    DoCmd.Close

    Else

    MsgBox ("Sorry, access denied!")

    End If

    End Sub
```

All input is welcomed. Thank you!

Comment: do you mean hide the password as they enter it?

Comment: @Sorceri - yes sir

Comment: Encrypt and then do what ?  Do you really mean encrypt, or just hide ?

Comment: you need to create a login form and not use the inputbox.  You can then use a textbox and set the Input Mask to display * instead of the characters.

Comment: @TimWilliams - simply to hide the text as the user is typing. Anything the user types is visible. passw0rd4 is seen as is and not as black circles. Maybe "encrypt" isn't the best word, still in the novice stage haha.

Comment: @Sorceri - do you mean using a macro instead?

Comment: I mean, in Access Create a new form.   Add a Label ("Enter Password"), add a text box with the mask set to the astrix ( so all text is seen as * ), add two buttons, Ok and Cancel.   You will need to add the code to the button click events to deal with checking the password and canceling the form.

Comment: @Sorceri - Ohhh i see, alright. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 3):

The input box does not have an option for you to mask the characters/hide the data entry. Make a form with a text box and set the input mask for the textbox to be **PASSWORD**. This should accomplish what you need/want.

Answer (score -1):

My quick "code free" solution is to use Font Name "Wingdings" for the password field. The occasional passer-by will not be able to read it; however, if you live in an hacker-rich environment, you definetly need a code solution, which unfortunately I cannot give...

Comment: The input mask is "code free" as well.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).